# Create key, value pairs based on the querydata

Tags: python, django, dictionary

python query to the DB as

```
m = Request.objects.filter(type__contains='mega')
```

and a queryset based on m as

```
x = m.values('set', 'value')
```

It returns values like

```
[{'value': u'sasi', 'set': u'ITEM1'}, {'value': u'babu', 'set': u'ITEM1'},{'value': u'unni', 'set': u'ITEM2'},...]
```

I am planning to create a dictionary based on the data. SO it will be like

```
{'ITEM1': [sasi, babu], 'ITEM2':[unni], 'ITEM3': [x, y, z] , ....}
```

How can I convert the above queryset into this dictionary format? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> data = [
...     {'value': u'sasi', 'set': u'ITEM1'},
...     {'value': u'babu', 'set': u'ITEM1'},
...     {'value': u'unni', 'set': u'ITEM2'},
...     {'value': u'x', 'set': u'ITEM3'},
...     {'value': u'y', 'set': u'ITEM3'},
...     {'value': u'z', 'set': u'ITEM3'},
... ]
>>> 
>>> data = sorted(data, key=lambda d: d['set'])
>>> import itertools
>>> {key: list(d['value'] for d in grp)
...  for key, grp in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda d: d['set'])}
{u'ITEM2': [u'unni'], u'ITEM3': [u'x', u'y', u'z'], u'ITEM1': [u'sasi', u'babu']}
```

You can skip `sorted` call if queryset is ordered by `set`.

Comment: You can use `operator.itemgetter('set')` instead of  `lambda`

Comment: @user3100115, You're right. I used `lambda` here for brevity.

Comment: @falsetru: It didnt worked in my case actually. Why there is a "{" before key

Comment: I did exactly as you said `import itertools
        data = sorted(x, key=lambda d: d['set'])
        {key: list(d['value'] for d in grp)
        for key, grp in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda d: d['set'])}
        print data`. In my pycharm editor it says `Statement seems to have no effect`

Comment: @vellattukudy, You need to assign the dict-comprehension back to `data`: `data = {key: list(d['value'] for d in grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda d: d['set'])}`

Comment: @vellattukudy, Or just print the dict-expression itself: `print {key: list(d['value'] for d in grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda d: d['set'])}`

Comment: How can I iterate through the values? So that I can print like `for every key print values in my html`?

Comment: @vellattukudy, `for value in dictionary.values(): do something with value` OR `for key in dictionary: do something with dictionary[key]`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
for item in x:
    data[item['set']].append(item['value'])
```

Comment: Great answer Daniel. But am getting a `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, ` when I print the data

Comment: Well, convert it to a dict with `dict(data)` at the end if it bothers you, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Because when I iterate through the dict just created as per your answer: `for k, v in data:
          print k `     Am getting an error as `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: That has nothing to do with defaultdict; for any dict or subclass, you need to iterate through `data.items()` if you want both keys and values.